# Spring boot app connecting Hive Datasource : java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hive, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am connecting to a Hive datasource with my spring boot app. Below is the datasource-config

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class HiveDataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${hive.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${hive.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${hive.password}")
    private String password;

    public DataSource getHiveDataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate getJDBCTemplate() throws IOException {
        return new JdbcTemplate(getHiveDataSource());
    }
}
```

This is the JDBC-Url that i connect to

> jdbc:hive2://hpeeeee.hpc.company.com:8443/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/Users/arun/Downloads/truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=password123;transportMode=http;httpPath=one/default/hive

I connect to hive database to get 8000+ records.. The connection works perfectly well and some times i get the below exception

> java.sql.SQLException:
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException

and some time i get the below exception

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Invalid SessionHandle:

When i googled the reason for these exception, i can see some responses telling that it is due to the issue with the Hive-Server...

**However when i restart my app (that connects to hive DB), this failure is gone and coming back after some time.**

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you check if the hive driver matches the hive distribution you are trying to connect? Sometimes having two different versions of hive dist. you can have similar issue.

Comment: when i restart my app, it works perfectly fine.. only after a idle period of certain time, i get the exception

Comment: What is the Hive URL?  Are you connecting through a load balancer?  If the balancer is not configured correctly, the connection may bounce between different instances of HiveServer2 and the connection will be rejected with "Invalid SessionHandle" since the other HiveServer2s do not have that client registered.

Comment: is there anyway to tackle it via Spring boot ? so that it terminates all the invalid session and gets a new one

Comment: I have updated my actual post with JDBC URL details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arun As one of your comment states ***"it works perfectly fine.. only after an idle period of certain time, i get the exception"*** This seems to me and connection pool issue. Due to active/idle/timeout properties after some idle time when a new request comes in it is not having a connection object properly available in the pool.

With Spring boot you can use and pool in a much better way like below then you have shown in the sample code above.

***In application properties file***

```
// These are tomcat connection pool properties.
// Sprign boot properties document link provided below 
spring.datasource.hivedb.username=
spring.datasource.hivedb.password=
spring.datasource.hivedb.url=
spring.datasource.hivedb.driver-class-name=
spring.datasource.hivedb.initial-size=<<define as per your load>>
spring.datasource.hivedb.validation-query=<<for hive select query>>
spring.datasource.hivedb.validation-query-timeout=3
spring.datasource.hivedb.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.hivedb.max-wait=60000
```

***In Java config file***

```
@Configuration
public class HiveDataSourceConfig {

@Bean(name = "hiveDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "spring.datasource.hivedb",ignoreUnknownFields = false)   public DataSource hiveDataSource() {
return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
    
@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
return new JdbcTemplate(hiveDataSource());
}
}
```

***Spring boot data properties document link***

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-properties

This document provide details of properties defined by spring framework for multiple connection pools supported by the framework. Use them as a reference to tweak them.

As shown in my example application properties you need to test and tweak them as per the need.